# Apple TV AVPlayerViewController HLS thumbnail of frame is absent while seeking paused stream. tvOS 11

Tags: avplayer, http-live-streaming, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller, video-thumbnails

Since tvOS 11, for out of the box AVPlayerViewController a thumbnail of the frame is absent while seeking a paused stream.
I checked the same HLS stream with tvOS 10 and I do see a thumbnail.

I have found open radar https://openradar.appspot.com/35261766
and a lot of developers and users complainings, but haven't found any solution.

Any suggestions on how can I return thumbnails back?

Answer (score 0):

The HLS stream needs to be published with this data. Refer to the Trick Play section in Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices

> **Trick Play**
>
> 6.1. I-frame playlists (EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF) MUST be provided to support scrubbing and scanning UI.
>
> 6.2. You SHOULD have one frame per second “dense” I-frame renditions. These are dedicated renditions that only contain I-frames.
>
> 6.3. Alternatively, you MAY use the I-frames from your normal content, but trick play performance is improved with a higher density of I-frames.
>
> 6.4. If you provide multiple bit rates at the same spatial resolution for your regular video then you SHOULD create the I-frame playlist for that resolution from the same source used for the lowest bit rate in that group.
>
> 6.5. The bit rate of I-frame playlists SHOULD be the bit rate of a normal playlist of the same resolution times the fps of the I-frame
> playlist divided by eight. (See I-frame bit rates versus normal bit
> rates.)
>
> 6.6. You SHOULD provide multiple I-frame Media Playlists with different bit rates.
> 6.7. As with normal video, there are many possible choices of bit rates for dense I-frame variants.
>
> 6.8. I-frame playlists MUST contain the EXT-X-I-FRAMES-ONLY tag.
>
> 6.9. The peak segment bit rate MUST be calculated according to the HLS specification.
>
> 6.10. If using fMP4, I-frame segments MUST include the 'moof' header associated with the I-frame.
>
> 6.11. For live/linear content, target durations for I-frame playlists MUST be identical to other media.
>
> 6.12. For VOD content, target durations of I-frame playlists MAY be different from the other media.
>
> 6.13. I-frame playlists MAY use a different video codec than the normal video segments.
>
> 6.14. For backward compatibility, some trick play content SHOULD be encoded with H.264.
>
> 6.15. If HDR trick play streams are provided, then they SHOULD be provided at all resolutions.
>
> 6.16. For backward compatibility, SDR trick play streams MUST be provided.